# How can i fix my collapsed embedded YouTube Videos?

Tags: html, video, youtube, embed

I have a page on my website that embeds a few Youtube videos. The videos load, but the actual viewing screens seemed to have collapsed and only show the top and bottom play bar of the embedded video.

Here is the link to the page : http://www.refillfinder.com/catalog/how-to-refill-home.html

It uses the standard YouTube iFrame HTML tag that is grabbed directly from the video on YouTube. In the past, it worked perfectly fine and the videos appeared, but I have no idea what could have changed to make them collapse. Any advice??

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change the height of your iframe component,
as we can see, in your css we have

```
iframe{ 
      border: 0 none; 
      height: 60px;
}
```

Try with a higher value.